# Need to Specifically Learn Scheme Knowing Java and Python

Tags: java, python, scheme, sicp

I would like to read SICP but I don't want to fully learn `Scheme`. I know Java, C#, and Python all very well, so would it be possible to pick up `Scheme` quickly while still getting the full value out of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just read it, the code is very simple.

`(f a b c)` means `f(a,b,c)`, and `(define (f a b c) ...)` means `f(a,b,c) { ... }`.  And, the *values*, not *variables*, have types (variables instead are generic pointers to values). That's all. :)

So just by reading the book you'll be able to pick up the Scheme as used in it -- this was the expressed intent of the authors, too.

After reading some, or even before, watch [the videos from the 80s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Op3QLzMgSY). It's great stuff.

Comment: Totally agree about the videos.. I enjoy seeing the Wizards themselves in action I have seen the whole bunch several times.  The videos might even be easier to comprehend than the same material in the book :-)

Comment: @Sylwester you're right, videos can be watched while reading, or even before. :)